# What does a #define directive without an argument do?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, header-files, preprocessor-directive

On Apple's opensource website, the [entry for stdarg.h](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1456.1.26/EXTERNAL_HEADERS/stdarg.h) contains the following:

```
#ifndef _STDARG_H
#ifndef _ANSI_STDARG_H_
#ifndef __need___va_list
#define _STDARG_H
#define _ANSI_STDARG_H_
#endif /* not __need___va_list */
#undef __need___va_list
```

What do the #define statements do if there's nothing following their first argument?

Comment: They simply define the macro to expand to nothing, but are useful with `#ifdef`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are sort of three possible "values" for an identifier in the preprocessor:

1. Undefined: we don't know about this name.
2. Defined, but empty: we know about this name, but it has no value.
3. Defined, with value: we know about this name, and it has a value.

The second, defined but empty, is often used for conditional compilation, where the test is simply for the definedness, but not the value, of an identifier:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
  // here we know we are C++, and we do not care about which version
#endif

#if __cplusplus >= 199711L
  // here we know we have a specific version or later
#endif

#ifndef __cplusplus // or #if !defined(__cplusplus)
  // here we know we are not C++
#endif
```

That's an example with a name that if it is defined will have a value.  But there are others, like NDEBUG, which are usually defined with no value at all (`-DNDEBUG` on the compiler command line, usually).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I think I get the purpose now. In your last example, `defined()` is just a macro operator built into C?

Comment: It's part of the C preprocessor.  You can read about `defined()` here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Defined.html

Answer (score 1):

They define a macro which expands to nothing. It's not very useful if you intended it to be used as a macro, but it's very useful when combined with `#ifdef` and friends—you can, for example, use it to create an include guard, so when you `#include` a file multiple times, the guarded contents are included only once.

Answer (score 1):

You define something like:

```
#define _ANSI_STDARG_H_
```

so that, later you can check for:

```
#ifdef _ANSI_STDARG_H_
```

Comment: So is it sometimes used as a sort of flag for different operating systems? Like `#define INT_IS_32` and then some other header file would be checking to see if int was 32 bits?

Comment: yep. another example: `#define TEST_MODE` and `#ifdef TEST_MODE`.